# 'AnyRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimators_'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I've been trying to use multiple regressor elements at a time with this function

```
def regressors(x_train,y_train,xtest,ytest):
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
    from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
    from sklearn.linear_model import ARDRegression,LinearRegression,SGDRegressor
    regressor = *AdaBoostRegressor(),*RandomForestRegressor(),*LinearRegression(),*SGDRegressor()
    for r in regressor:
        r.fit(x_train,y_train)
        pred = r.predict(xtest)
        print(r.__class__.__name__)
        print(mean_squared_error(pred,ytest))
        print(r2_score(pred,ytest))
        print('\n')
regressors(x_train,y_train,xtest,ytest)
```

This always returned a traceback of
`AttributeError: 'AdaBoostRegressor' object has no attribute 'estimators_'` or any regressor that has been set to be the first in the pointers list
although any of these regressors has been working well when I was using them individually as in this piece of code

```
rfr = RandomForestRegressor()
abr = AdaBoostRegressor()
abr.fit(x_train,y_train)
rfr.fit(x_train,y_train)
pred = abr.predict(xtest)
predr = rfr.predict(xtest)
print(mean_squared_error(ytest,pred),r2_score(ytest,pred))
print(mean_squared_error(predr,ytest), r2_score(predr,ytest))
```

but I don't want to write a spaghetti code so I tried this function
Can anyone help me overcome this error, I want to know why it uses estimators when I do not specify any estimator to be there in the function code
I've seen some solutions using `df.at()` but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have to write this as regressors aren't iterables:

```
regressor = [AdaBoostRegressor(),RandomForestRegressor(),LinearRegression(),SGDRegressor()]
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that then, and this solution worked well for me Thank you so much